# how to get all column values in string in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

how to get all column values in string in laravel query,
my query is,

```
$profile = DB::table('app_user')->where([
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => md5($request->password),
      'app_id' => $request->app_id
  ])->select('id as app_user_id','id','name','email','user_image','activate')
    ->first();
```

this return in object

```
 "app_user_id": 2857687,
 "id": 2857687,
 "name": "zahid"
```

I want to output like this

```
"app_user_id": "2857687",
"id": "2857687",
"name": "zahid"
```

I am using laravel 5.4

please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can cast MySQL data like this.

```
$profile = DB::table('app_user')->where([
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => md5($request->password),
      'app_id' => $request->app_id
  ])->select(DB::raw('CAST(id AS varchar) as app_user_id, CAST(id as varchar) as id, name, email, user_image, activate'))
    ->first()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. @Shahadat Hossain  can we get all fields in a string by using any other approach because I have many more data to convert in string

Comment: As I know from MySQL casting, this is the best option. you can read this article https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-cast-and-convert/

Comment: @Zain truly speaking, I do not prefer casting data in MySQL. If you are using this date in web front-end then I recommend casting data in front-end with js. it will keep simple and looks great.

Answer (score 1):

convert into **unsigned integer** using mysql [CAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp) function

```
$profile = DB::table('app_user')->where([
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => md5($request->password),
      'app_id' => $request->app_id
  ])->select(\DB::raw('CAST(id AS UNSIGNED) as app_user_id'),\DB::raw('CAST(id AS UNSIGNED) as id'),'name','email','user_image','activate')
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert integer to string in mysql query like this:

`..
 ->selectRaw('CAST(id as CHAR(50)) as app_user_id', 'name', ...)
 ->first();`